# Oracle: Connection intermittent issue using JDBC url

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

SQL developer provides multiple methods to connect to a database instance.

If I choose the `Basic` method, which provides `hostname`, `port` and `SID` into input box separately, database connection runs without any issue.

However, if I choose `Advanced` method, which provides the following JDBC url in a whole：

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:SID
```

and hit `Test` button, sometimes the status shows `Success`, but sometimes it pop up an error message like this:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
```

So why and how there is such a difference with both methods? Is it a bug from SQL developer?

### UPDATE 1

I found the issue happens exactly when I run a Java EE application with JNDI connection to the same database instance, so database instance listener cannot tolerate more than one access if one of them is JNDI? I think I just make that up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the problem, in short the issue can be solved either of the two choices:

1. Increase the size of connections allowed by Oracle
2. Decrease the size of connections allowed by JNDI

The 1st solution is operated by DBA, but the second can be implemented by developer, in my application's JNDI settings(We test JNDI on Tomcat), the max connections allowed to the pool is too many to current Oracle service can handle:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/schema_A" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:orcl"
    username="app_A" password="app_A" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />
```

`maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"` is too much hence the error message, so I change it to

```
<Resource name="jdbc/schema_A" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:orcl"
    username="app_A" password="app_A" maxActive="1" maxIdle="1" maxWait="-1" />
```

Now everything is working without issues...cheers..